# How to extract only file name from the path?

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file, cmd.exe

I am running the code,

```
set /p "filepath=Drag and drop your file >"
cls
echo Your file name is : %filepath%
pause>nul
```

**output i am getting**

```
Your file name is : c:/users/philip/desktop/file.txt
```

When user drag and drop there file in command prompt and press enter it shows full file path as output..

**expected output**

```
Your file name is : file.txt
```

But, what i am expecting is, only the file name with extention..like shown above as output.

**Note : File path and File name may varies..**

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252980/how-to-split-the-filename-from-a-full-path-in-batch which has a fine solution.

Comment: here are two similar methods shown:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10393248/get-filename-from-string-path

Comment: Phillip - Did you get what you needed for your question? You simple just reference the passing in or dragged and dropping of the file name as `%~nx1`.... Specifically `%~nx1` will give you the file name and extension only.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
set /p "filepath=Drag and drop your file >" 
cls 
for %%a in ("%filepath%") do echo Your file name is: %%~nxa
pause >nul
```

Here `n` and `x` are the modifiers of the for meta variables. To learn more about them, open cmd and type `for /?` and look at the end.